# How to convert .xlsm file to .xlsx file without using any specific excel packages

Tags: python, excel

i am scratching my head from last two days for converting .xlsm file to .xlsx file.Problem is that most of the examples are using some packages like win32.client  or openpyxl or editpyxl etc.

the problem is that i am having limited access of packages for python. i dont have these packages.Can somebody suggest me a script that can convert .xlsm file to .xlsx. I am having "pandas" installed in my server.

can someone point me to a code in python that can convert .xlsm to .xlsx

Comment: Your best bet is probably to figure out a way to install something like `openpyxl`. What's preventing you from installing this package?

Comment: Those packages have the answer.

Comment: installing a package on a shared server will take atleast a month in my company and i can't wait that long.

Comment: @rikki, you may not need any kind of elevated privileges. Can you work in a virtualenv? Using a library that's designed to do this kind of work is almost certainly the right approach.